# Overriding Cypress' before and after methods

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

We are using Cypress.io to build our automation suite. We have a requirement to seed our database before every test and to clear the data afterward. This could be done like below.

```
describe('Our test suite', function() {
  before(function () {
    //loadDbSeed is a custom command that will load the seed file based on the spec file
    seed = cy.loadDbSeed()
    cy.task('seed:db', seed)
  })

  it('should be true', function() {
    //Some test with some action followed by an assertion
    cy.visit('/some-page')
    cy.get('[data-cy="identifier"]')
      .click()
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })

  after(function () {
    // clearDb is a custom command that will clear out the DB.
    // We are still debating if we must clear the DB after the tests.
    // But we might still need to do some common actions for the entire suite after
    cy.clearDb()
  })
})
```

The problem we see is that the same `before` and `after` operations will be required for all our test suites. So we would like to override these methods so that our tests are something like this.

```
describe('Our test suite', function() {
  before(function () {
    // DB seeding is done automatically
    // Write only custom before steps required for this test
  })

  it('should be true', function() {
    //Some test with some action followed by an assertion
    cy.visit('/some-page')
    cy.get('[data-cy="identifier"]')
      .click()
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })

  after(function () {
    // DB clearing is done automatically
    // Write only custom after steps required for this test
  })
})
```

How do we achieve this? I have been digging around in the Cypress code and haven't found anything obvious.

Comment: You can just add the `before()` and `after()` methods to '/cypress/support/index.js` and they get run with every suite. Note you can still have suite-specific `before()` and `after()` inside the suite itself, in fact you can have as many times as you like - they are invoked in the order they appear (support ones first).

Comment: Richard, thanks a lot. We will try this and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Cypress docs, using `after` isn't recommended - [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks). I'd caution against setting data globally, will you really need it for every test? If you need to enter data on a per-test basis at some point, will that conflict with this global data? You could do something like this on a per test basis:

```
describe('Our test suite', function() {
  beforeEach(function () {
     cy.then(async () => {
       await MyDatabaseService.resetdata()
       await MyDatabaseService.createSomeData()
     });
   });

  it('should be true', function() {
    //Some test with some action followed by an assertion
  })
})
```

I've also had to nest some tests as follows when specific tests needed specific data (sorry if some of the formatting here is a bit out, hopefully it'll make sense!):

```
describe('Our test suite', function() {
  beforeEach(function () {
     cy.then(async () => {
       await MyDatabaseService.resetdata()
       await MyDatabaseService.createSomeData()
     });
   });

  it('should be true', function() {
    //Some test with some action followed by an assertion
  });

   describe('These tests need more data, this is a nested describe', function () {
     before(function () {
       cy.then(async () => {
         await MyDatabaseService.addSomeMoreData()
       });
     it('this test uses the extra data', function () {
     // Do some funky tests here
    });
   });
 });

})
```

For the second tests above, the test will run all three database actions.

Upshot is, if you clear data *before* you run your tests then it makes things much clearer.

I hope that helps. I'm new to Cypress myself and it can be hard to drop that (bad?) habits we've used for some time in Selenium!

Comment: Simon,


Thanks a lot for your inputs. I didn't make it clear in my question (and apologies for that), but we are not actually seeding the data globally. Each spec or test will have its own seed JSON file and we just need a mechanism to load the relevant seed file in the before block without having to rewrite the same code again. Does that make sense?

Comment: Regarding the use of after, as I mentioned in we are still debating this. One aspect that is not clear to me is if each test doesn't clear up the database, how do we ensure the tests are independent of each other? E.g., Test 1 creates a new item in the DB and verifies the creation works. Test 2 is an independent verifies the number of items in the list with search and filter. How do we ensure Test 1 doesn't affect Test 2 if we don't reset and load data only relevant to Test 2?

Comment: I am guessing that in this case, Cypress recommends Test 1 just removes the item it added instead of having a common after block that resets the entire database. Is that right?